# How to Loop a Autohotkey Script:

Tags: autohotkey

Can i make a script that when held down "q" moves the cursor to the center and then again if any additional keys are pressed it adds to the loop. for example i am pressing the q hotkey and it is moving my mouse cursor to the center now when i press the "w" key it should loop both the "hotkey q" and "w" key like this "qwqwqw".

Currently, i have the following code:

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

q::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SysGet, screenWidth, 0
SysGet, screenHeight, 1
MouseMove, screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2
Loop
{
    SendInput, q
    Input, key, V L1 M
    if ErrorLevel
        break
    if (key = "w" or key = "d" or key = "z")
    {
        SendInput, %key%
        Loop
        {
            Input, key, V L1 M
            if (ErrorLevel or key != A_ThisHotkey)
                break
            SendInput, %key%
            SendInput, q
        }
    }
}
return
```

Tested:

When I run this script it moves the cursor to the center of the screen but when I press any additional key, for example, the key "w" it doesn't loop it instead it just registers "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" like it normally does.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think should happen when you press `w`? It's not a hot key by itself.

So while holding `q` you then press `w` you are going to have to stop in your loop to test the key state:

```
Sleep, 1000  ; pause every second
if GetKeyState("w")  ;  check if w is pressed
```

or try

```
KeyWait, w, D T1  ; Wait up to 1 seconds for w to be pressed
```